# Trouble with MEF ExportFactory and batch exports

Tags: c#, .net, mef

We are running into an issue when using an ImportMany that uses an ExportFactory with MEF where exports composed with a CompositionBatch are rejected.  Below is an example program that works fine:

```
class Program
{
    public CompositionContainer Container;
    private Program()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        Container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public interface ICalculator
    {
        String Calculate(String input);
    }

    public class MyOtherCalculator : ICalculator
    {
        public string Calculate(string input)
        {
            return "blah";
        }
    }

    [Export]
    public class CalculatorCollection
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(ICalculator))]
        public IEnumerable<Lazy<ICalculator, ICalculatorMetadata>> calculators;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var typeName = typeof(ICalculator).FullName;
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        metadata[CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName] = typeName;
        metadata["Name"] = "blah blah blah";
        var definition = new ExportDefinition(typeName, metadata);

        batch.AddExport(new Export(definition, () => new MyOtherCalculator()));
        p.Container.Compose(batch);

        var collection = p.Container.GetExportedValue<CalculatorCollection>();
        var calculator = collection.calculators.First().Value;
    }
}

public interface ICalculatorMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

But, if I change the ImportMany on the CalculatorCollection to use an ExportFactory

```
[Export]
    public class CalculatorCollection
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(ICalculator))]
        public IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ICalculator, ICalculatorMetadata>> calculators;
    }
```

it will no longer contain the export composed through the batch.  We did find a workaround, shown below, but it seems like a dirty hack as it relies on the use of internal type names and the export needs to know that it will be imported with an Export Factory.

Does anyone know the proper way to fix the batch export?

Thanks for any help.

Workaround program:

```
class Program
{
    public CompositionContainer Container;
    private Program()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        Container.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public interface ICalculator
    {
        String Calculate(String input);
    }

    public class MyOtherCalculator : ICalculator
    {
        public string Calculate(string input)
        {
            return "blah";
        }
    }

    [Export]
    public class CalculatorCollection
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(ICalculator))]
        public IEnumerable<ExportFactory<ICalculator, ICalculatorMetadata>> calculators;
    }

    public class MyComposablePartDefinition : ComposablePartDefinition
    {
        private ExportDefinition _definition;

        public MyComposablePartDefinition()
        {
            var typeName = typeof(ICalculator).FullName;
            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            var metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            metadata[CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName] = typeName;
            metadata["Name"] = "blah blah blah";
            var definition = new ExportDefinition(typeName, metadata);

            var contractName = "System.ComponentModel.Composition.Contracts.ExportFactory";
            var typeName2 = typeof(ComposablePartDefinition).FullName;
            var metadata2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            metadata2[CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName] = typeName2;
            metadata2["ProductDefinition"] = definition;
            metadata2["Name"] = "some factory";
            Func<object> factoryFactory = () =>
                new ExportFactory<ICalculator>(
                    () => Tuple.Create<ICalculator, Action>(new MyOtherCalculator(), () => { }));

            _definition = new ExportDefinition(contractName, metadata2);
        }

        public override ComposablePart CreatePart()
        {
            return new MyComposablePart(_definition);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ExportDefinition> ExportDefinitions
        {
            get { return new[] { _definition }; }
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ImportDefinition> ImportDefinitions
        {
            get { return Enumerable.Empty<ImportDefinition>(); }
        }
    }

    private class MyComposablePart : ComposablePart
    {
        private ExportDefinition _definition;
        public MyComposablePart(ExportDefinition def)
        {
            _definition = def;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ExportDefinition> ExportDefinitions
        {
            get { return new[] { _definition }; }
        }

        public override object GetExportedValue(ExportDefinition definition)
        {
            return new MyOtherCalculator();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ImportDefinition> ImportDefinitions
        {
            get { return Enumerable.Empty<ImportDefinition>(); }
        }

        public override void SetImport(ImportDefinition definition, IEnumerable<Export> exports)
        {
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        var typeName = typeof(ICalculator).FullName;
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        var metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        metadata[CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName] = typeName;
        metadata["Name"] = "blah blah blah";
        var definition = new ExportDefinition(typeName, metadata);

        var contractName = "System.ComponentModel.Composition.Contracts.ExportFactory";
        var typeName2 = typeof(ComposablePartDefinition).FullName;
        var metadata2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        metadata2[CompositionConstants.ExportTypeIdentityMetadataName] = typeName2;
        metadata2["ProductDefinition"] = definition;
        metadata2["Name"] = "some factory";
        Func<object> factoryFactory = () =>
            new ExportFactory<ICalculator>(
                () => Tuple.Create<ICalculator, Action>(new MyOtherCalculator(), () => { }));

        batch.AddExport(new Export(definition, () => new MyOtherCalculator()));
        batch.AddExport(new Export(new ExportDefinition(contractName, metadata2), () => new MyComposablePartDefinition()));
        p.Container.Compose(batch);

        var collection = p.Container.GetExportedValue<CalculatorCollection>();
        var calculator = collection.calculators.First().CreateExport().Value;
    }
}

public interface ICalculatorMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and ended up using your workaround.